# Of the three properties that a set of sentence may have: "consistent", "complete", "is a theory", which pairs imply the third?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Of the three properties that a set of sentence may have: "consistent", "complete", "is a theory", which pairs imply the third?

It is Exercise 1.4.42 in Hinman's *Fundamentals of Mathematical Logic*. I guess if a set of sentence $\Delta$ is a complete propositional theory, then it is consistent. As it is similar to Proposition 1.4.29 in this book:

> Every finite consistent and complete set of sentences is consistent (has a model).

I tried to find a model of such $\Delta$ . I chose truth assignment $V$ :

$$
V(p_n) = 
\begin{cases}
\mathrm{T},p_n\in \Delta,  \\\\
\mathrm{F},\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

To prove it is truly a model, I tried to prove $\varphi\in \Delta\iff V(\varphi) = \mathrm{T}$ by induction.

For atomic sentences it is easy to prove. For $\psi = \neg \varphi$, as $\Delta$ is a complete set,

$$
\neg \psi \in \Delta \iff  \psi \notin \Delta \iff V(\psi)\ne \mathrm{T} \iff V(\neg \psi)= \mathrm{T} 
$$

Then the problem goes to $\varphi\lor \psi$ . I don't know how to continue by using "$\Delta$ is a theory".

Comment: See **Def.1.4.5** page 43 for *propositional theory*: a set of sentences closed under tautological consequence.

Comment: See **Def.1.4.8** page 44 for *consistent* and *complete*. Consistent does not imply complete.

Comment: I tried to review these definitions. However, I still can't figure out whether "complete"+"is a theory" $\to$ "consistent" is a true direction. If so, can I complete my proof this way?

Comment: The def of complete is: proves either A or bot-A but not both. Thus, it implies consistency.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I finally figured out I don't need such complex proof.